# Trying to use FreeType with CImg

Tags: c++, freetype

I work with some code that uses FreeType2:

```
void drawText( FT_Face &face, cimg_library::CImg < unsigned char > &image, const int &heightText, const std::wstring &text, const int &leftTopX, const int &leftTopY, int &width, int &height, unsigned char fontColor[] = NULL, const int separeteGlyphWidth = 1 ) {

    width = 0;
    height = 0;

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes( face, 0, heightText );
    FT_GlyphSlot glyphSlot = face->glyph;  

    int shiftX = leftTopX;
    int shiftY = 0;
    for( int numberSymbol = 0; numberSymbol < text.length(); ++numberSymbol ){

        shiftY = leftTopY;

        bool isSpace = false;
        FT_ULong symbol = text[ numberSymbol ]; //FT_ULong symbol = text.at(numberSymbol);
        if (symbol == ' ') {
            symbol = 'a';
            isSpace = true;
        }

        if( FT_Load_Char( face, symbol, FT_LOAD_RENDER ) ) throw "Error, glyph not load!! \n";

        shiftY = heightText - glyphSlot->bitmap.rows;
        if ( shiftY < 0 ) shiftY = 0;

        std::cout << "char: " << (char) text.at( numberSymbol ) << " \tshiftY = " << shiftY << "\t rows = " << glyphSlot->bitmap.rows << "\t extra = " << ( glyphSlot->advance.y >> 6 ) << "\n";

        if ( !isSpace ) drawGlyph( glyphSlot, image, shiftX, shiftY, fontColor );

        shiftX += glyphSlot->bitmap.width + separeteGlyphWidth;

        if( height < shiftY + glyphSlot->bitmap.rows ) height = shiftY + glyphSlot->bitmap.rows;
        width = shiftX;

    }

}


std::string str = "Let me speak from my heart!";
std::wstring wStr( str.begin(), str.end() );

int width, height;
drawText( face, myCImg, 50, wStr, 50, 50, width, height );
```

but it doesn't work as expected. The output image is like that:
[image]

There's some strange behavior with symbols: "y", "f", "p". How to put it lower?

It looks like I should to do something with **glyphSlot->metrics.vertAdvance** but I don't know how to properly use it.

Comment: just glancing at the documentation I would just try to use `bitmap_top` like `shiftY = heightText - glyphSlot->bitmap_top;`

Comment: @PeterT, hah, thanks man! It really works! :) You can add this info as answer - I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a quick look at the [online reference](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_GlyphSlotRec) it seemed like the value to use for the Y-offset should be based on `bitmap_top` if pixel coordinates are wanted.

So I would recommend changing the line

```
shiftY = heightText - glyphSlot->bitmap.rows;
```

to

```
shiftY = heightText - glyphSlot->bitmap_top;
```

This seems to be also confimed by looking at the [basic tutorial](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html) which uses these values in the following manner:

```
/* now, draw to our target surface */
my_draw_bitmap( &slot->bitmap,
              pen_x + slot->bitmap_left,
              pen_y - slot->bitmap_top );

/* increment pen position */
pen_x += slot->advance.x >> 6;
```

Comment: Thanks again! That really helped me!